# Defining where a JavaScript split function starts and ends

Tags: javascript, function, split

I have created the below function to allow me to take the following string 'my00.00--p.mbbb.vocap:3062/test.html' which is within a table and change the 'p' to a 'b'. The results I get is as follows 'b/test.html'. Below is the script..

```
function test(table, col) {
        var table = document.getElementById(table);
        for (x = 1; x < table.rows.length; x++) {
            var temp = table.rows[x].cells[col].innerHTML;
            table.rows[x].cells[col].innerHTML = temp.replace(temp.split('//')[1].split('/')[0], 'b');
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Did you try to debug each part of your splitting "temp.replace(temp.split('//')[1].split('/')[0], 'b');" execution before asking this question ?

Comment: @JulienAlary I did indeed. I get a slightly different results changing split('/')  to split('.') but still not what I would expect.

Comment: There is no '//' in 'my00.00--p.mbbb.vocap:3062/test.html' so You're first split is necessary undefined.

Comment: @JulienAlary my bad I missed that in my question. 'http:// my00.00--p.mbbb.vocap:3062/test.html'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your error is you misuse [replace() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

```
table.rows[x].cells[col].innerHTML = temp.split('//')[1].split('/')[0].replace('p', 'b');
```

You can find more details here : http://jsfiddle.net/rLkdyr9e/1/

Comment: Thanks Julien. However this seems to give the same result unfortunately. Which is 'b/test.html and not 'my00.00--b.mbbb.vocap:3062/test.html'

Comment: Impossible my stuff results 'b/test.html'. Did you look after my jsfiddle ?